# TypeError: TransformerBatchNormEncoderLayer.forward() got an unexpected keyword argument 'is_causal'

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, conda, transformer-model

I am trying to run the github - gzerveas mvts_transformer
After jupyter install -r requirement.txt, it show this error and I do not know how to fix.

I've ask GTP and it suggest this question might due to different version of the environment. So, I opened a terminal in AWS and try to create a new environment based on other similar studies environment. MTSIT-yarkin06-venv.yml(for conda)

But I am not sure whether my solution is right? Coz acutally I just want to fix that 'is_causal' key words.
By the way I also try to find 'is_causual' in github, but I didn't find. Is there a place that I can search all the code in that github program? I appriciate if could provide picutres, as a new learner I am not familiar with the Specific words.
And I am not sure whether the teriminal is keep runing.
Lastly I am not sure when it can finnaly finished preparing, it is that because I am using VPN, or most person will be slow at this stage. Coz I feel I am using AWS-SageMaker and it should not be slow due to my using of VPN.
![https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXCXs.jpg(https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXCXs.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

You need torch version for example 1.13.1.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I'm providing this response because I believe some people may be coming here through Google search to solve the issue.

The error you're encountering stems from an update in PyTorch where the addition of `is_causal` to the `forward` method of `TransformerEncoderLayer` causes the error. Therefore, to address this problem, you need to modify the `TransformerBatchNormEncoderLayer` so that even if you don't use `is_causal`, it is still assigned to the parameters. Essentially, the updated TransformerEncoderLayer function declaration includes a parameter called `is_causal`.

To make the modification, change from:

```
def forward(self, src: Tensor, src_mask: Optional[Tensor] = None,
            src_key_padding_mask: Optional[Tensor] = None) -> Tensor:
```

to:

```
def forward(self, src: Tensor, src_mask: Optional[Tensor] = None,
            src_key_padding_mask: Optional[Tensor] = None,
            **kwargs) -> Tensor:
```

After this modification, is_causal will be assigned to kwargs, preventing errors from occurring.